# Error: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, ms-access, between, unhandled-exception, mismatch

I've made a program about flights using C# linked to an Access DB (for school).
However, after doing all the basics, I wanted to score some extra points.

My DB consists of two tables: `reizigers` (passengers) and `vluchten` (flights). All the classes and variables should be defined correctly.

My problem: I want to be able to *search* for flights *between* certain *cost* ranges.

However, after executing the query and thus trying it, it gives the error:

> Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

In my DB, the cost is `kost`, and it's just a single Integer (e.g., 240).

Does anybody have any idea what it might be?

[image: repository]
[image: wpf window, entry]

Comment: Please put code into your post as text. You can't expect people to re-type to work out what is wrong and help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KistMin` and `KostMax` are two integers and I suppose that also the datatable field `Kost`, used in your WHERE clause, is of type integer.

But your query encloses the two variables between single quotes and this transform them in strings. The database doesn't like to compare an integer field containing a numeric value against a text (also if this text is composed of digits) and complains with the mentioned error.

A simple fix is removing the quotes around the two values that you put in your sql where condition and fixing the [syntax of the BETWEEN predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709364(v=vs.85).aspx). (Not sure what actually that syntax produce, probably a boolean result evaluated against the Kost field, not what you expect)

```
".... WHERE Kost BETWEEN " + KostMin + " AND " + KostMax;
```

In your context (MS-Access, using integers) there is no concern for Sql Injection, but it is a good practice start using parameterized queries.

Comment: Hey, Now i don't get any error anymore, which is nice. However when I push the button nothing seems to happen,
I dont really have a clue what goes wrong..

Comment: uh oh, that's because the syntax for BETWEEN is wrong, let me fix the answer